# Digital Mixing Consoles

Tags: hardware

I am searching for a Digital Mixing console with inbuilt Converter and inbuilt Reverb FX.

Roght now i found this one http://www.thomann.de/gb/presonus_studiolive_1602.htm.

What is your experience with Presonus, and do you know any good alternatives?

Peace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PreSonus is a good choice.  Behringer also has some good choices as well.  The real question is what is your application?  Are you planning to record or is this for live sound?  Give some examples of what it is you are trying to accomplish because it can make a difference.

Comment: I want to use the Console for Live streaming for companies, Voice over recordings and Hobby-Music recording :)

Comment: So its mainly to feed in 4-6 Mics -> Reverb and compression would be very helpful